# Не срабатывает chrome.runtime.onMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Добрый день.
Пробую написать небольшое расширение для chrome. При выделении произвольного текста на сайте в контекстном меню браузера должна появляться новая строка, по нажатию на которую текст определенным образом преобразовывается.
Мой manifest.json выглядит следующим образом:

```
{
    "name": "CEPS",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "do something",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["ceps.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["cepscl.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

В cepl.js описано контекстное меню. На событие нажатия повешена отправка сообщения:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, {
    test: "test"
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

cepscl.js, соответственно, слушает и выполняет код при приеме сообщения:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("test");
    console.log(request);
    modify_selection();
    sendResponse("response");
});
```

Однако, ничего не происходит, в консоль возвращается undefined (каллбэк sendMessage). Насколько я понимаю, событие onMessage не вызывается.

**UPD**
Я пробовал стандартные варианты связи фонового кода с контент-скриптом (примеры из документации), и они дают такой же результат. Далее я попробовал посылать сообщение из контент-скрипта в фоновый скрипт:
cepscl.js

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage('test');
```

ceps.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request == 'test') console.log('test', request);
});
```

В консоли ничего не происходит.
Складывается впечатление, что мой контент-скрипт cepscl.js изолирован от фонового скрипта. С чем это может быть связано?
**UPD**
После повторного обновления расширения в панели расширений сообщения из контент-скрипта стали отправляться, а фоновый скрипт их принимает. Однако, обратная связь по прежнему не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Пример отправки сообщения из background script (в вашем случае ceps.js) в content script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ "active": true,"currentWindow": true }, function (tabs) {        
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "My message!"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делал пункт контекстного меню так:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Test", contexts: ["link"], onclick: function(info, tab) {
}});
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create

Comment: Проблема немного в другом. Сам пункт контекстного меню я создал, а вот запустить с помощью него функцию в контент-скрипте не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Вы перепутали API. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` нельзя вызвать из фоновой страницы.

`chrome.extension.sendMessage`вообще не существует.

`chrome.extension.sendRequest` - устаревший метод.

Насколько я понял, вам надо передать сигнал из фоновой страницы в контент-скрипт. Это можно сделать только через механизм [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect)